# Git blame committed line

Tags: git

Is it possible somehow for GIT to find which commit introduced a specific line of code in a specific file? This is assuming that there have been many commits since that line was added. Or is this something that must be done in a script while looking at the git blame of all the commits for the file in which the line is present?

To clarify

Original file->Line Added to file and committed -> Many other commits adding other lines and changing the code

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use `git blame -l filename` to get the SHA1 hash from when the line was changed.

You also can use --reverse:

> --reverse
>
> Walk history forward instead of backward. Instead of showing the revision in which a line appeared, this shows the last revision in which a line has existed. This requires a range of revision like START..END where the path to blame exists in START.

See: http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-blame.html

Comment: This is taking me in the right direction. it seems L is an argument to git blame that would allow a line or range of lines to be tracked. I'll investigate a little more and post my findings.

Comment: see my edit you can use reverse and -L for the range then you get the commit

Comment: Using -L found the commit at the top. If I used --reverse I'm sure it would help as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

It seems you can use git log -L to check file.
For example, I want to check the commits for file.c, line from 55 to 60:

```
git log -L55,60:file.c
```

Answer (score 5):

You can blame against the specific code string like this.

```
git log -S 'THE-CODE'
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the line hasn't changed since it's been added, then simply:

`git blame <that file>` and then look for the line that you're after.

If the line has been modified since it's been added, you can still `git blame` to find out the last commit on which the line was altered, and then `git checkout <sha>~1` (where `sha` is the sha that shows up in the original `git blame`) and `git blame` again to go back in the history for that line.

Comment: I added clarification above. I want to find it after many commits were done. Otherwise I just do git blame as you said.

Comment: This doesn't seem like it would give me the commit specifically that introduced the line. Rather, I would have to use git blame to iterate finding it myself. I was hoping GIT would be capable of finding this for me.

Comment: I don't know of any other way other than to `git blame` that file continuously and find the line manually. I don't think Git has a way of doing it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Chronological history of line 42 with commit messages and diffs:

```
git log --reverse -L 42,42:file.py
```